# Plugin development: create new file dialog using FileDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jface, savefiledialog

I am trying to open dialog that ask for name of the new file and the place to put it, and then create new file in the right place.
But, save dialog (which is the most similar dialog I saw) save the file that opened.
But, I want that if I right click on file and I choose to save part of the file in another place, a save dialog will open and it's will save part of file in the chosen place (I have function that create the specs I want in the new file).

I tried this :

```
      String[] FILTER_NAMES = { "Spectra Files (*.spectra)"};

  // These filter extensions are used to filter which files are displayed.
  String[] FILTER_EXTS = { "*.spectra"};

  // User has selected to save a file
  FileDialog dlg = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.SAVE);
  dlg.setFilterNames(FILTER_NAMES);
  dlg.setFilterExtensions(FILTER_EXTS);
  String fn = dlg.open();
```

but, when I press on save, I want it to create the new file in calling the function:

createSpectraFile();

That is creating a new FILE with the content I want.

There is a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question right, but if you want to create a file from the result of the `FileDialog` do this:

```
String fn = dlg.open();
if (fn != null) {
    createSpectraFile(fn);
}
```